# Do spaces matter in a crontab

Tags: cron

It's not clear to be from the manpage for crontab. IS extra white space allowed between the fields? e.g., if I have this:

```
1 7 * * * /scripts/foo
5 17 * * 6 /script/bar
31 6 * * 0 /scripts/bofh
```

is it safe to reformat it nicely like this:

```
 1  7 * * * /scripts/foo
 5 17 * * 6 /script/bar
31  6 * * 0 /scripts/bofh
```

?

Comment: simple, yes it is.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Yes extra space is allowed and you can nicely line up your fields for readability. From `man 5 crontab`

```
Blank lines and leading spaces and  tabs  are  ignored.
```

and

```
An environment setting is of the form,

   name = value

where the spaces around the equal-sign (=) are optional, and any  sub‐
sequent non-leading spaces in value will be part of the value assigned
to name.
```

For the fields itself the man pages says:

```
The fields may be separated  by  spaces or tabs.
```

That should be clear: multiple spaces are allowed.

Comment: +1 for having the actual quotes from the man page that I missed. space"S"

Answer (score 26):

Yes Extra whitespace is permitted.  Consider:

```
#Mins  Hours  Days   Months  Day of the week
10     3      1      1       *       /bin/echo "I don't really like cron"
30     16     *      1,2     *       /bin/echo "I like cron a little"
*      *      *      1-12/2  *       /bin/echo "I really like cron"
```

I always add column headers because I'm  too lazy to remember the order of all the numbers, but here's what that crontab produces:

> This crontab should echo "I really like cron" every minute of every
>   hour of every day every other month(Every Even month). Obviously you would only do that
>   if you really liked cron. The crontab will also echo "I like cron a
>   little" at 16:30 every day in January and February. It will also echo
>   "I don't really like cron" at 3:10 on the January 1st.